# Nginx - Create Multiple Sub Domains

Tags: nginx

I would like to create multiple subdomains using nginx from 1 IP address.  So it would be something like this:

```
http://demo1.192.168.0.27
http://demo2.192.168.0.27
```

Someone already asked this question in the past.
[nginx - two subdomain configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568981/nginx-two-subdomain-configuration)
I tried the same way but I'm not able to do it.

Here's my code:

```
events {
}

http {
   server {
      server_name demo1.192.167.0.27;
      root /data/sites/demo1;
      index index.html;

      location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
      }  
   }

   server {
      server_name demo2.192.167.0.27;
      root /data/sites/demo2;
      index index.html;

      location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /404.html;
      }  
   }

}
```

When I go to

```
http://demo1.192.168.0.27
http://demo2.192.168.0.27
```

It said, This site can’t be reached

Not sure why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create subdomains on IP addresses.

In the answer you're referencing, they're using domain names, like this:

```
server_name sub1.example.com;
server_name sub2.example.com;
```

That's why it works, as opposed to what you have, with IP addresses:

```
server_name demo1.192.167.0.27;
server_name demo2.192.167.0.27;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain names are not public. You can resolve to a DNS provider to make them public.

You also can add `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx       demo1.192.168.0.27` to your local hosts file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, to make them avaliable to your local machine.