# routing subdomains to a specific port in nodejs

Tags: node.js, routes, port, subdomain, host

I have two react frontend servers (example1 and example2) listening on two ports on MyDomain.com:
MyDomain.com:4000 accesses example1
MyDomain.com:5000 accesses example2

I have two subdomains, example1.MyDomain.com example2.MyDomain.com
I want to create a third nodejs server that will listen on port say 3000 and route requests to ports 4000 and 5000 depending on the subdomain accessed.
example1.MyDomain.com will be routed to MyDomain.com:4000
and
example2.MyDomain.com will be routed to MyDomain.com:5000

could not find an example that addresses port numbers except for ngnix
I also tried using proxy middleware but the examples show how to route according to the suffix after the .com and that is not what I need.
Thanks for any help,
Amnon

Comment: This sounds like a reverse proxy with domain based handling. I can recomend NGINX for that.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to use one of the popular proxies/load balancers for that Nginx, HAProxy, Envoy, Traefik.

If you want to do it specifically with node.js you will need create proxy server on your own,but that is not a good idea because the apps mention above already have that functionality and they are built specifically for that use case

Comment: You can find the instructions for nginx here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568981/nginx-two-subdomain-configuration

Comment: Thanks David, I'll look into Nginx then.